# How to properly initialize copy constructor (of constructor with class as reference)

Tags: c++, constructor

How do you initialize a copy constructor of constructor that has as reference a class. I simply do not know what to put after the colon in order to initialize it.

```
class Me{
 public:   
    Me (const otherMe& t)
    :other_me(t)
    {}
    //copy constructor
    Me(const Me& me)
    : /*what do you put here in order to write 
    the line of code bellow. I tried t(t), and gives me the 
    warning 'Me::t is initialized with itself [-Winit-self]' */

    {cout << t.getSomthing() << endl;}

 private:
    const otherMe& other_me;
};
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to have happen.  Do you want the copy of the `Me` to refer to the same object the source does?

Comment: `: other_me(me.other_me)`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have two classes, `Value`, and `Wrapper`:

```
class Value { // stuff... }; 

class Wrapper; // This one contains the reference
```

We can write the constructor and copy-constructor like so:

```
class Wrapper {
    Value& val;

   public:
    Wrapper(Value& v) : val(v) {}

    Wrapper(Wrapper const& w) : val(w.val) {}
};
```

This wold also work if `Value&` were a const reference! In addition, if you can write `Wrapper` as an aggregate, it'll automatically get a copy constructor:

```
class Wrapper {
   public:
    Value& val;

    // copy constructor automatically generated
};
```